# Nodejs Export module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 files in my nodejs project,

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var designtokenfile= require ('./designtokenfile.js');
var designtokendb = require ('./designtokendb.js');
var DesignFactory = require('./DesignFactory.js');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/edit0.json';

app.get('/Tokens', function(req, res) {
var store=DesignFactory.storeDesign(ex);
console.log(store);

var data=store.load();

res.end(data);
});
app.listen(3001);
console.log('Listening on port 3001...');
var ex=process.env.TYPE;
console.log(ex);
```

DesignFactory.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
var designtokenfile = require ('./designtokenfile.js');
var designtokendb = require ('./designtokendb.js');
var TYPE=process.env.TYPE;
module.exports=
{
storeDesign: function(TYPE) {
if (TYPE == 'file') {
return designtokenfile;
}
else if (TYPE == 'db') {
return designtokendb;
}
}
};
```

designtokenfile.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fsstore = {
save : function() {
fs.writeFile('output.txt');
},
load : function() {


var data = fs.readFileSync('edit0.json','utf8');
return data;
}
};

module.exports.designtokenfile=fsstore;
```

I am new to nodejs,when we give /Tokens it is giving the error load is not defined or store.load is not a function. storeDesign method inside the DesignFactory should return an object through which i need to call load method inside the designtokenfile. But its not happening in my code. please help me am lost. (assume that file is the value for ex in function call storeDesign)

Comment: Whether all these files are in same folder???

Comment: yes all files are in same foldere

Answer (score 0):

Look at this piece of code:

```
app.get('/Tokens', function(req, res) {
    var store=DesignFactory.storeDesign(ex);
    console.log(store);

    var data=store.load();

    res.end(data);
});
```

Now *after* you define this closure (which uses the variable `ex`), you actually *define* the variable `ex`:

```
var ex=process.env.TYPE;
console.log(ex);
```

So this variable will not be within the scope of your closure. Move the variable definition before the closure-definition like this:

```
var ex=process.env.TYPE;
console.log(ex);
app.get('/Tokens', function(req, res) {
    var store=DesignFactory.storeDesign(ex);
    console.log(store);

    var data=store.load();

    res.end(data);
});
```